# Secure connection in sending an email with WFA

Tags: winforms, email, c++-cli, send

I'm using this function:

```
void SendEmail(String ^ sendTo, String ^ sendFrom, String ^ subject, String ^ body, bool enableSsl, char* user_login, char* user_pass)
        {
            SmtpClient^ client = gcnew SmtpClient();
            MailMessage^ msg = gcnew MailMessage();

            String ^ user = gcnew String(user_login);
            String ^ pass = gcnew String(user_pass);

            System::Net::NetworkCredential^ smtpCreds = gcnew System::Net::NetworkCredential(user, pass);


                client->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                client->Port = 587;
                client->Credentials = smtpCreds;
                client->EnableSsl = enableSsl;

                MailAddress^ to = gcnew MailAddress(sendTo);
                MailAddress^ from = gcnew MailAddress(sendFrom);

                msg->Subject = subject;
                msg->Body = body;
                msg->From = from;
                msg->To->Add(to);

                client->Send(msg);
        }
```

for send email. I have problem with 9th line - if I set static string like this:

```
System::Net::NetworkCredential^ smtpCreds = gcnew System::Net::NetworkCredential("adress@gmail.com", "my_password");
```

it's ok - mail will be send, but when i'm trying using my variable from other function application crashed with:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException'
>   occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The SMTP server requires a secure connection
>   or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1
>   Authentication Required. Learn more at

PS. Yep, SSL is enable.

I have login and password from file:

```
char * getAccountData(int marker, int lb_kont)
{
    char wyjscie[256], login[256], password[256];
    char * korektor = "||";
    char * schowek;
    string zawartosc_pliku;

    ifstream NowyPlik;
    NowyPlik.open("C:\\account.db");
    for(int a =1; a<=lb_kont; a++)
    {
        getline(NowyPlik, zawartosc_pliku); 
        strncpy(wyjscie, zawartosc_pliku.c_str(), 128);
        schowek = strtok( wyjscie, korektor );
        strcpy(login, schowek);
        schowek = strtok( NULL, korektor );
        strcpy(password, schowek);
    }

    NowyPlik.close();
    if(marker == 1)
        return login;
    if(marker == 2)
        return password;
}
```

and for function which send mail i've set `getAccountData(1,lb_kont)` and `getAccountData(2,lb_kont)` as `char* user_login, char* user_pass`. Next i change char * to String (6th and 7th line in my first post).

Comment: using your variable from another function exactly how? Are you passing it in as a parameter to another function or what?

Comment: I forgot it, sorry, check my first post again.

Comment: There is nothing in that code that is incorrect, Step through it with the debugger and figure out exactly where the exception occurs, And work on fixing that.

Comment: @johnathon :When i put `getAccountData(1,a)` into SendEmail function as _String ^ sendFrom_ (yes, i changed type char * to String earlier) i have warning:

_Additional information: An invalid character was found in the mail header: ''._

Comment: well, have you figured out what character is invalid?

Comment: @johnathon: yep, invalid character is space (' ') but when i displayed `getAccountData(1,a)` in richTextBox there wasn't any space :/
I think that i have mistake when i changed char* to String. But i don't know how I can repair that.

Comment: String^ is inherently unicode, char* is not, try using wchar_t* intsted.

Comment: @johnathon: it's still not working. I change converting metod from char* to String: `String ^ user = Convert::ToString(user_login);` etc. for pass - now I have new error:
_Additional information: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address._
(In line: `MailAddress^ from = gcnew MailAddress(sendFrom);`)